# How to make table header in Vue clickable?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to make a table header in Vue clickable?
I already use v-on:click but nothing happened.

```html
<tr>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center">No.</th>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center" v-on:click="sortBy">Jenis Barang</th>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center">Ubah</th>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center">Hapus</th>
</tr>
```

I tried using @click but nothing happened also :/. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with Vue. Generally speaking, when you want to make a row clickable, you'll have to add an event to every cell of this row. Also, I would suggest to generate your `<th>` tags using a `v-for` directive and you will only need to write your `@click` once.